# Do we need to specify the same binding in WCF server and client?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I get the following error when calling wcf service from client.

> The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to
>   a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).

It says that the sender and receiver need to use the same binding. Does that mean, if I use `BasicHttpBinding` on the server the same binding needs to be specified in the client?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: **YES!** The client and server **must match** on their bindings and binding configurations (security, reliability etc. settings) - no communication possible otherwise!

Comment: mark - Your comment contains a full answer to the question. Is there any reason you did not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> It says that the sender and receiver need to use the same binding.
>   Does that mean, if I use BasicHttpBinding on the server the same
>   binding needs to be specified in the client?

In simple case **Yes**.

But some times both the client and server can use different bindings for communication when there is a **router** involved between them. For ex. when the service uses tcp binding (netTcp) and the client uses http binding(basicHttp) in reals case they can't talk to each other but having a [routing service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517421.aspx) between them makes the communication is possible. Of course the routing service has to to use the basic http binding.